# What size screws for mounting ENT electrical box with outer ears

Tags: electrical

I am looking to mount an ENT electrical box, using the holes provided in the outer ears of the box as pictured below. What would be the appropriate type/size of screw to mount this to a wood stud?[image]

Comment: I would go with "Whatever is on hand and fits through the holes", but wait for the electricians to chime in.

Comment: Yeah I figured like a #8 - 1 inch flat head wood screw, I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Joist hanger nails. 8d nails, though you might end up with nail sticking out the far side of the stud, which can get bloody if you don't waste time bending them over, and nailing in boxes is all about speed. The better choice in screw is a pan-head (flat underneath, not conical like a flathead) but plenty of boxes have been mounted with drywall screws (bugle-head) and survived.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean with a pan-head being able to better tighten the box to the screw. Thanks!

Comment: Metal boxes and any random deck or drywall screw.  The very fact that you have to ask that question is yet another reason not to use plastic boxes.  A box has one job, contain heat and fire from arc faults.  Plastic boxes are *literally made of petroleum*. They have boron added to reduce their flammability, but still...

Answer (score 2):

Code is not real specific on the screw size or type but I have seen inspectors flag Sheetrock screws in plastic boxes. why?  Over tightened the plastic can crack on some boxes. I usually use #8 pan /washer style (modified truss is another name I found them under). the wider head secures the box plastic or metal better than a run of the mill screw.
But the reason I started using them is inspectors like them.
I use 3/4” or 1” whatever is cheaper sometimes the 1” are.